# php email attachment issue

Tags: php, email, attachment

this is my php code for send **pdf** file with attachment in email. now i have issue with attachment of outlook and hotmail. if i'm send email(with pdf file attachment size 2 mb), it show me corrupt file(in outlook and hotmai) and show file in some **348 bytes**.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRUlb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XdiR.png)

but is work perfect in **gmail, yahoo mail and other mail**.

this is my code for php email attachment

```
    $seller_name = "seller name";
    $file_name = "po2181492084075.pdf";
    // test eamil
    $seller_email_id = "someemail@outlook.com";
    //$seller_email_id = "dsomedata@gmail.com";
    $file_name = $file_name;
    $path = "agreementpdf";
    $mailto = $seller_email_id;
    $subject = "Notification of order";
    $bodytext = "Hello ".$seller_name.",\nThis  Order has been sent to the Seller . You will be notified when their review has been completed.\n Regard \n onlinecode Team";

    $file = $path . "/" . $file_name; 
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

    // a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
    $separator = md5(time());

    // carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
    $eol = PHP_EOL;
    $message = $bodytext;
    // main header (multipart mandatory)
    $headers = "From: Team <contact@onlinecode.org>" . $eol;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;
    $headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol;

    // message
    $headers .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol;
    $headers .= $message . $eol;

    // attachment
    $headers .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $file_name . "\"" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol;
    $headers .= $content . $eol;
    $headers .= "--" . $separator . "--";

    // sleep for create eamil header 
    sleep(3);
    //SEND Mail
    $eamil = mail($mailto, $subject, "onlinecode", $headers); 
    echo $eamil;
```

i have no idea what is issue and and how to resolve it, any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: Use a library for this, like SwiftMailer or PHPMailer

Comment: @tereško : let me try it, but this code is work in perfect in gmail, yahoo mail any idea?